# Saving Form Region Data in Outlook 2007

Tags: c#, outlook

I am creating an Outlook 2007 add-in that adds a form region to an appointment that a User creates. What is the best way of storing & associating the data that the User inputs in my form to the appointment they have generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where would you like to save it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._appointmentitem_properties.aspx

?

Comment: That is my question. In my new form region I am allowing the User to set agenda items. So, I am not sure where I would save those agenda items. Do I save them in one of the AppointmentItem properties?

Comment: It depends what you want to do with them. It is your decision. I might be inclined to save them in the body or to create a custom property. You might even want to add them to a database to help with writing the minutes.

Comment: Thanks, this has helped my plan of attack.